# how to assign response data of api get request in angular

Tags: angular, api, get, xmlhttprequest

i am making a get request to an api endpoint, which sends a json object ,i want courses array from data property.but i am not able to, do not know what am oi doing wrong ,should in convert json to object ....
the error is
Property 'key' does not exist on type 'Object'.

here key should be equal to "data" and data is property of the json.

my component is

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { pipe } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators'
import { C } from './c.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-course',
  templateUrl: './course.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./course.component.css']
})
export class CourseComponent implements OnInit {
 courses :C[]=[];
  constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.fetchCourses();
  }

  private fetchCourses() {
    this.http.get('http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/courses/')
    .pipe(map( responseData =>{
      const coursesArray = [];
        for(const key in responseData){
          if(responseData.hasOwnProperty(key)){
             if(key === "data")
             {
               coursesArray.push(...(responseData.key.courses))
             }
          }
        }
        return coursesArray
      }))
    .subscribe(responsec=>{
      this.courses=responsec;
    })
  }

}
```

json from api

```
{
    "status": "sucess",
    "numberOFResults": 5,
    "data": {
        "courses": [
            {
                "images": [],
                "tutors": [],
                "_id": "611c8899e135aa2c9cd39796",
                
          
            },
            {
                "images": [],
                "tutors": [],
                "_id": "611c8899e135aa2c9cd39794",
                "name": "arduno uno",
                
            },
            {
                "images": [],
                "tutors": [],
                "_id": "611c8899e135aa2c9cd39795",
                "name": "c/c++",
                "duration": 8,
                
            },
            {
                "images": [],
                "tutors": [],
                "_id": "611c8899e135aa2c9cd39798",
                "name": "ms office",
                "duration": 4,
               
            },
            {
                "images": [],
                "tutors": [],
                "_id": "611c8899e135aa2c9cd39797",
                "name": "web development",
                
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: From your response structure you can directly access courses like `responseData.data.courses`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`key` here is of type string and you are accessing the property using . (dot). You need to access it using the bracket [] syntax.

Change this

```
coursesArray.push(...(responseData.key.courses))
```

to

```
coursesArray.push(...((responseData as any)[key].courses))
```

Comment: yes,it's working.but what was the problem befor??

Comment: You were accessing the object property using . (dot) and the key is of type string, in such cases when key is string, we need to use [] bracket syntax to access object property.

Comment: no problem, if it solved your problem, considering upvoting/accepting the answer :)